# Steering wheel making clunking sound when being turned

Tags: repair

I have a Mazda 2, and recently, I took my car in for a service, and the mechanic told me that he noticed the steering wheel was making a 'clunking' sound as it is being turned.

The mechanic told me that he has safety concerns about this and recommends that I should get it looked into as soon as possible. He feels that there may be something loose about it and wants to charge an hourly rate to investigate.

I noticed that it was doing this as well and initially I was planning to take the car in to have it investigated, but today, it was not doing it.

When it was doing this, I suspect that it was because I had parked the car the night before on an uneven surface and the car was tilted to that of the driver's side. Since then, I had parked it on levelled ground and the sound seems to have gone away.  I recall it doing something similar in the past when I parked it on unlevelled ground.

Something about leaving the car on unlevelled ground seems to cause the problem.

Is this a serious problem that I should take the car in to have investigated?

Comment: It could be that the steering lock mechanism is faulty and catching when you turn the wheel. You need to get this checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to be safe than sorry - get it checked out.

Take it to a specialist tire/suspension company. They'll put it on the lift and check out everything underneath for free. Could be a worn CV joint - whatever it is, it should be pretty obvious when it's up in the air. They'll give you a quote to fix it, and then it's up to you whether you let them do it, or your current mechanic.

Parking on 'unleveled ground' shouldn't cause any issues like this in a car which has no problems.

Comment: Thanks. I think you might be right as the sound is back. Maybe the turns that I was making was not as sharp before and it did not trigger the sound.